# Was The Mysterious Stranger the first story to explore the idea of "artificial reality"?

Tags: the-matrix, mark-twain

I guess in the case of MS, artificial reality is not a completely accurate term but I hope it is clear I meant "fake" rather than say machine-generated.

In a way, the novel is sort of a distant ancestor of The Matrix and I wonder if it is the very first book in which the main character discovers his universe does not really exist although in the case of The Matrix there is a real world (I think -- don't know what subsequent movies or books have revealed) and in The Mysterious Stranger the main char is sort of like a Boltzmann Brain and I wonder if Twain was aware of this concept -- I suspect not although they lived at roughly the same time.

Comment: I don't see that *The Matrix*, *The Mysterious Stranger* and *Boltzmann Brain* are related.  In *The Matrix* consensus reality is a computer simulation.  In *The Mysterious Stranger* it is not clear that Satan isn't speaking _metaphysically_ about our inability to truly know if anyone else is a "real" person; it's more closely related to Plato's Allegory of the Cave.  And the Boltzmann Brain concept seems to assert that there is no such thing as "reality" at all.

Comment: Doesn't the idea that the physical universe doesn't really exist go back at least to 1710 and Bishop Berkeley's philosophy of immaterialism a.k.a. subjective idealism?

Comment: @DavidW I'll respectfully disagree on the Boltzmann Brain definition (though one could take a similar idea and scale it up to something like a random emergent god digital physics  computer in something more basic than our universe that imagines our universe - as far as i know no one has coined a term for it) but enthusiastically agree that Plato is the best earliest example of reality is more perception than reality - given how wispy to nonexistent the connection is between the 2 stories is.

Comment: From about the same era as Plato, there is also the "dreaming butterfly" text of Zhuangzi.  I leave it up to the OP whether the parables or either  Plato or Zuangzi count as a "story".